# How set style combobox programmatically (WPF)

Tags: wpf, combobox, styles

I'have write this code for apply template to ComboBox.

This is code on App.xaml

```
        <Style x:Key="{x:Type ComboBox}" TargetType="ComboBox" x:Name="selectedStyleTrigger">
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="150"/>
            <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
                        <Grid>
                            <ToggleButton Name="ToggleButton" Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}" Grid.Column="2" 
                                          Focusable="False" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen,
                                Mode=TwoWay,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ClickMode="Press" />
                            <ContentPresenter Name="ContentSite" IsHitTestVisible="False" Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}" ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}" Margin="3,3,23,3" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                            <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox" Style="{x:Null}" Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBox}" 
                                     HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="3,3,23,3" 
                                     Focusable="True" Background="Transparent" Foreground="White" 
                                     Visibility="Hidden" IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}" 
                                     Width="250"/>
                            <Popup Name="Popup" Placement="Bottom" IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}" 
                                   AllowsTransparency="True" Focusable="False" PopupAnimation="Slide" 
                                   Width="200">
                                <Grid Name="DropDown" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" 
                                      MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}" MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">
                                    <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder" Background="#004460" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#004460" />
                                    <ScrollViewer Margin="4,6,4,6" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                        <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
                                    </ScrollViewer>
                                </Grid>
                            </Popup>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="False">
                                <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="MinHeight" Value="95"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="False"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger SourceName="Popup" Property="Popup.AllowsTransparency" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="CornerRadius" Value="0,0,2,2"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="Margin" Value="0,-1,0,0"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEditable" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="ContentSite" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

I have this class it extends ComboBox:

```
public class ComboBoxExtends :ComboBox
{
   public LOCAL_PE_AttivitaXParametri parametri { set; get; }
}
```

Now I insert on Panel the ComboBox in this way:

```
ComboBoxExtends comboBox = new ComboBoxExtends();
comboBox.Style = Resources["selectedStyleTrigger"] as Style;
grid.Children.Add(comboBox);
```

I set style "comboBox.Style = Resources["selectedStyleTrigger"] as Style;" but I don't see the style.

How can I fixed it?

Reguards

Comment: try this.FindResource method.

Comment: The defined style targets the `ComboBox` type, not `ComboBoxExtends`. Try changing the `TargetType` to `ComboBoxExtends`, note about the namespace containing that type and refer it in your XAML code properly.

Comment: Not found because ComboBoxExtends is not recognized. I have ComboBoxExtends.cs

Comment: Please tell about the namespace of your control. You have to use the markupextension `{x:Type}` to specify the `TargetType`.

Answer (score 0):

You have created a `Style` for the `ComboBox` and are trying to apply it to your custom `ComboBoxExtends` class which is not a `ComboBox`. In order to declare a `Style` for your custom class, you will need to add an XML Namespace Prefix that points to the assembly where it is declared... perhaps something like this:

```
xmlns:Local="clr-namespace:YourAppName.OptionalFolderName"
```

Then you can refer to your custom class using this prefix:

```
<Style TargetType="Local:ComboBoxExtends" x:Key="selectedStyleTrigger">
    ...
</Style>
```